I don't see any point in taking part

"No matter how you vote, everything's decided in advance," a young woman called Svetlana tells me. "I don't see any point in taking part."

Source: https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-68543919
How would you analyze the bold part?

"see any point is a phrasal verb. "in" is a preposition that links the  "see any point" part and the "taking part" part.
"any point in taking part" is a noun phrase and the object of "see".


Imho it's a bad idea to classify see any point as a phrasal verb. Normally, "phrasal verb" is understood to mean a verb with a preposition or adverb or both, the meaning of which is different from the meaning of its separate parts. But seeing / not seeing a (literal or metaphoric) point just means what it says - you don't need to look it up in a dictionary the way you'd need to do in order to understand a "normal" phrasal verb if you weren't a native speaker, and had never encountered something before.

...nor is it really useful to classify any point in taking part as a "noun phrase". The actual noun is point, and personally I don't see the point in classifying the last two words there as a noun phrase. Just say it's a determiner (the) and a noun (point). And it's certainly not likely to be helpful to say the point in classifying the last two words there as a noun phrase is a "noun phrase".

No to #1. When a preposition attaches closely to a verb ("Please see to this now"), we attach special meaning to the pair, beyond the verb's basic meaning. @FumbleFingers shows us this is plain old vanilla "I don't see" in everyday "I don't view or understand this" meaning.

To "see a point" in something is to recognize in it some meaningful purpose.

I would wash, but I don't see the point. I'm just going to get dirty again.
I agree. I don't see any point in it.
Me neither. I want nothing to do with this soap and water business. I don't see any point in taking part in that.

The prepositional phrase "in it" (in your example "in taking part") is supplemental.  "taking part" (to take part in something) is to participate in it.  You can understand 'taking part'  as a nominal form of the verb there, a gerund.
"take part" can occur alone:

We're going to have a seance Friday night after the football game. Would you like to take part? We're going to try to summon the spirit of Attila the Hun.


<I don't see any point in taking part.> It seems to me that "any point in taking part" is a noun phrase and the object of the verb "see". Is this completely wrong?

@Englishgood Yes, "any point in taking part"  is a noun phrase  and it is the object of the verb "don't see". It's not always clear here, when a questioner asks about a particular phrase, whether they understand the meaning or not.   I had no idea why you might think that see any point was a phrasal verb.  "To see a point  (in something)" is a collocation but not a phrasal verb.

"I don't see //any point// in taking part."
I don't see=the verb, transitive here
any point = direct object of the verb see
idiom = point in [doing something], here, taking part [implied: in elections]
There is no phrasal verb in the sentence. phrasal verbs are a verb + a preposition as in stand up or sit down.
